# jquery join mouserdown and click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div can draggable, when user click on it, it will highlight it & change color to red.

I'm using click

```
$().click(function(){});
```

However if user click & hold it, it wont change color because mousedown, if I use `mousedown();`
when user release mouse, the color will gone.

My question is, is that possible to join click & mousedown together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$().on('click mousedown',function(){}) // Use 'click' and 'mousedown' combine as shown
```